# Is my bash script accurate enough to check if the list of images are being referred anywhere in directory?

Tags: bash

I have a list of images which I wanted to delete if they are not being referred anywhere. My directory consists of multiple directories and within them, there are `.js` files. I need to search each image name in the above files. If they are referred anywhere, I need to output them so I will retain those images.

My script goes like this: I am trying to check each image in the following `.js or .json` files in the entire directory ( includes multiple directories inside) and output them to c.out if any of these files contain the above image name. Am I doing it right? I still could see some images are not coming in output even if they are being used.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='images.txt'
echo Start
while read p; do 
    echo $p
    find -name "*.js" | xargs grep -i $p > c.out
    done < $filename
```

images.txt contains:

```
a.png
b.png
c.jpeg
....
```

Comment: Each loop iteration overwrites `c.out`.

Comment: `find /path/to/proj/dir -name '*.js' -o -name '*.json' | xargs grep -Ff pic_list.txt` maybe all you need. where `pic_list.txt` is a one-line per filename input `.txt` file. ... `man grep` will fill in details. Results wil be more certain if all files contain no space or other non-alphnumeric chars. But test, test , test ;-). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Why `xargs` when you can `find -exec ... +`?

Comment: Put `> c.out` after the `done`, if you want the entire loop's results to end up there (if the `echo $p` is informational logging for the user, not output, then send it to stderr where informational and diagnostic logs belong: `echo "$p" >&2`). And run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, fixing the bugs it finds (there are some obvious issues around names with spaces that would happen due to missing quoting; even if you don't expect any unusual names, better to fix your code so you aren't inviting trouble).

Comment: @melpomene ; I prefer using `xargs` because it offers more options regarding parallel processing, but yes, then there is `gnu-parallel` with **lots** of options (That wasn't around on SunOS, though). Just for my info, does `exec` know now to deal with the `-prinf0` formatted results? Thanks and good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: your command above is giving results for only the last line in the file ( pic_list.txt ) I checked with two sets of inputs and observed this. Would you suggest any further change ?

Comment: was your `pic_list.txt` created on an MS Windows machine? If so, preprocess it (one tome) with `dos2unix pic_list.txt`. OR if you remove the last line of the file, does a new file get processed? (not sure what would cause that). Good luck.

Comment: Also, check your version of `xargs` for a `-V` (or `-v`) (verbose/debug) to have it display each iteration of `grep srchTarg file1 file2 file.... filen` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Keep a text file with list of images ( one name per line ), use `dos2unix file_name` if the file is generated/ created on Windows machine

Step 2: Run `find /path/to/proj/dir -name '*.js' -o -name '*.json' | xargs grep -Ff pic_list.txt`

You get the list of paths where those images are being referred.

Thanks [@shelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) for the answer

Comment: Good show! I think you want/need to parenthesize the `-o` conditions, i.e. `... \( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.json' \)...` . Otherwise you may be searching files that you don't need to search. Redirect both versions of output to separate files and see if there are any differences. Good luck.